# Create icons for and run different programs on different versions of Windows in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to use code variables to take decision during installation for `[Icons]` and `[Run]` sections, but I don't know if I'm wrong or not.

My `[Code]` section is :

```pascal
[Code]
var 
  myW7Val: string;

function GetMyW7Val(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := myW7Val;
end;

function IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(Major, Minor: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Result :=
    (Version.Major > Major) or
    ((Version.Major = Major) and (Version.Minor >= Minor));
end;

function IsWindows8OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 2);
  if not Result then
    myW7Val := '1';  
  myW7Val := '0';
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  IsWindows8OrNewer
  Result := True;
end;
```

And my `[Icons]` section is:

```
[Icons]
#if "{code:GetMyW7Val}" == '0'
  Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
  Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Tasks: desktopicon
  Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; \
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
#elif "{code:GetMyW7Val}" == '1'
  Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"
  Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
  Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
    Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
#endif
```

I would like to use the three first entries if `myW7Val` is `0` and the others if `myW7Val` is `1` . But for the moment I have a mistake and no values.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your literal question, use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```pascal
[Code]
function IsWindows8OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 2);
end;
```

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
  Check: not IsWindows8OrNewer 
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
  Tasks: desktopicon; Check: not IsWindows8OrNewer 
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; \
  Check: not IsWindows8OrNewer 

Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Check: IsWindows8OrNewer 
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; \
  Check: IsWindows8OrNewer 
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; \
  Check: IsWindows8OrNewer
```

---

Though that's an overkill, there are [`MinVersion` and `OnlyBelowVersion` parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams) for selecting entries for specific Windows versions:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
  OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
  Tasks: desktopicon; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; \
  OnlyBelowVersion: 6.2
 
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; MinVersion: 6.2 
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; \
  MinVersion: 6.2
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppLanceurName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppLanceurExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; MinVersion: 6.2
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to select application name and filename, to avoid having to duplicate the `Icons` entries:

```pascal
[Code]
function IsWindows8OrNewer: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsWindowsVersionOrNewer(6, 2);
end;

function GetAppName(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsWindows8OrNewer then Result := '{#MyAppLanceurName}'
    else Result := '{#MyAppName}';
end;

function GetAppExeName(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsWindows8OrNewer then Result := '{#MyAppLanceurExeName}'
    else Result := '{#MyAppExeName}';
end;
```

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{code:GetAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{code:GetAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{code:GetAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{code:GetAppExeName}"; \
  Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{code:GetAppName}"; \
  Filename: "{app}\{code:GetAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
```